# How can I carry missiles on stealth bombers?

Tags: freeciv

I want my stealth bombers to carry missiles and nuclear units. Since this is not the default function of stealth bombers in Freeciv, is there a way to modify the configuration files to allow stealth bombers to carry missiles and nuclear units?